# Is it possible to take Screenshot of GLSurfaceView from another thread in android?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, glsurfaceview

I am trying to capture the screen shot of my android application from onDrawFrame function of my Renderer. But it is dropping the frame and freezing the application till the process is complete. I am trying to do it on a different thread but no success. Is it possible to get the screen shot on a different thread.

Comment: Post some code, multi-threading this situation should be possible, it just depends on how you are doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't perform the `glReadPixels()` from another thread, because the EGL context can only be current in one thread at a time, and you have no control over it with GLSurfaceView.

However, 95+% of the time spent grabbing a screen shot from GLES is spent on PNG/JPEG compression and disk I/O.  So if you make the `glReadPixels()` call from `onDrawFrame()`, and then hand the data off to a new thread, you should be able to continue running while the screen shot is processed in the background.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned a direct read may be impossible from another thread but there are other ways.

Instead of drawing your scene directly to the surface view you may draw it to a frame buffer object (FBO) with attached texture and then redraw the texture to your main buffer. This is a pretty standard procedure for post processing and such and does not have a high performance impact. To realize this you actually just need to look into how to create the FBO, bind it before the drawing begins and the rest of your code should keep as it is. Then also add the code to redraw the FBO texture on the screen by binding the main buffer (index 0 should do).

For the screenshot on a separate thread you now need to create a new thread and a new context which is set on that thread. The new context must be shared with the main one (I believe there is a constructor that accepts the main context for that) so you may share the texture. Now the fun part: When you want to take the screenshot you need to create a new texture, attach the new texture to the FBO, detach the old texture. By doing so you kind of steal the texture to which the content is drawn and you can do whatever you want with it and on any thread you want. So put it into your secondary thread and on that context you may create another FBO, bind it and read the pixels from it on that thread. Do not forget to cleanup though.

Some caution is advised though. This kind of procedure may be good when you make a relatively small amount of screenshot. If one screenshot is not completely done before another one begins you will inflate in memory usage and your app will most likely crash. So be careful not to do that, create some kind of locking mechanism or limit the number of screenshot processing in progress. And this is not just for openGL, the same issue may occur when simply encoding the image data.

And just a note on your original idea: Even if you could use the surface view on a separate thread and read pixels from its main buffer you may not expect you will get a good result. The buffer may be drawn to while you are reading so it would be possible you would get chunks of data from different frames. Still this is just in theory because the truth is the buffer would simply be locked and your application would crash while trying to access it. So this is in no way possible and even if it was the result would be unpredictable.

Comment: Be careful -- sharing textures between contexts on different threads can have race conditions. I got this wrong in Grafika; see https://github.com/google/grafika/issues/36 .

Comment: And that is why I say you need to "steal" the texture. You need to replace the current texture you draw to with a new one. You could actually do double buffering by using 2 textures.